# How to incorporate random variables into integration?

Tags: python, random, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to compute an integral that contains a lognormal variable, but i'm not sure if I am introducing the random variable in the right way in the code. I have some code below and a picture (mathjax is not working for me) of the equation I would like to integrate:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import math 
import scipy.integrate as spi

rand = np.random.lognormal(0.0162,0.180)

def fun1(s):
    return s ** 2

def fun2(s):
    return math.exp( rand * spi.quad(fun1,0,2)[0])

def fun3(s):
    return s * fun2(s)

spi.quad(fun3,0,2)
```

You can run the above code and each time that you run it you will get a different answer which is indicative that the `rand` variable is being pulled from the LogNormal distribution. However, there are two ways that I can think of the `rand` variable is working in the operation.

1) The random variable is being assigned some constant value from the lognormal distribution, call it *a*, and when the integral is being computed, the program treats *a* like any other constant throughout the entirety of the integration. A similar analogy would be if you integrated 2x from 0 to 2, we know what happens with the 2.

2) Because the integrand has to be evaluated multiple times through some type of approximation algorithm, is the random variable changing on each evaluation of the integral. To be a random variable, I think this is what would be the ideal outcome.

A third option is that I am wrong about either of my two ideas on how the random variable is working within the overall integration. If somebody has any insight on how you could incorporate random variables, or confirm that I am doing it correctly, please comment below.

Comment: `np.random.lognormal` draws a single sample from the lognormal distribution, so (1) is correct. What do you try to achieve? Compute the distribution of the integral? Besides, your functions don't match the formula: rand should be in the exponential in `fun2`, not in `fun3`.

Comment: I just want to calculate the integral where the integrand can be thought of as the product of a random variable and a non-random variable. So if you look at the D(s) equation, you could instead imagine that being something far more simple where ```D(s) is the integral from 0 to 2 of `the integrand rho * s ```. Thanks for catching that mistake, I have just been playing around with the code, copied the wrong one by accident.

Comment: A function of a random variable is a itself a random variable. Asking what value `D(s)` has does not make sense. You can ask for a realization of `D(s)`, which is what your code computes, or you can ask how those realizations are distributed. The second question can be answered by drawing many realizations to estimate the probability density function of `D(s)` or its moments (mean, variance, etc.).

Comment: *"I just want to calculate the integral where the integrand can be thought of as the product of a random variable and a non-random variable."*  That is a problem from [stochastic calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_calculus).  `scipy.integrate.quad` is not designed to integrate a stochastic process, and it will probably fail or produce an answer that is nonsense if you attempt to use it for that.

Comment: @ Warren Weckesser So if the random variable ```rho```  was inside D(s) then this would be a problem that falls under stochastic calculus, and thus requires a different approach in computing the integral.